# python pdfkit token authentication

Tags: javascript, python, access-token, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I need to convert a javascript intensive webpage given an URL like `domain.com?client_id=test_client&token=ggvv68566fgjj` into pdf, if I open the URL into browser it open rights away but if using pdfkit code-

```
import pdfkit
url=domain.com?client_id=test_client&token=ggvv68566fgjj
pdfkit.from_url(url, 'out.pdf', options = {'javascript-delay':'9000'})
```

does fetch the partial page because it can not authenticate.

As it is a wrapper of wkhtmltopdf I tried these on terminal

```
wkhtmltopdf  --custom-header "Authentication" "Token ggvv68566fgjj" --custom-header-propagation --javascript-delay 5000 --debug-javascript "domain.com?client_id=test_client&token=ggvv68566fgjj" output.pdf
```

Access header authentication error is raised and pdf does not contain all data as API authentication failed.

Any suggestions and advice would be of great help.

Comment: first check web page in `private mode` to see if it need to login. And maybe you will have to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser, login, and download PDF.

Comment: webpage is loading properly in private mode also without login.Using selenium and firefox gecko driver it can be done but since gecko driver is heavy weight and i need to release it in production, it will be better if it could be done using pdfkit.